# set theory definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

n,m is positive integer satisfying $n \ge m$

An undirected graph $S_{n,m} =(V_{n,m},E_{n,})$ defined as follows:

$V_{n,m}=\{{A|A \, is \, a \,subset \, of \, {1,2...n}}\}$

$E=\{\{{A,B}|A,B \in V_{n,m} $the element contained only in one of A and B exactly m exist$\}$

i need to draw $S_{2,1} , S_{2,3}$

$V=\{\{\},{1},{2},{3},{1,2}\}$

but why i dont understand the definition of edge here? is this mean $A \cup B$?

can someone explain to me?

Comment: Can you quote the exact definition of the set $E$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your definition, but perhaps what you mean is $$E=\{A,B\in V_{n,m}| |A\varDelta B| = m \}$$

Comment: @Chiray i'm not sure too in problem there is no symbol definition just word.., but "there are exactly m elements included in only one of A and B " , here i'm not sure what is B and do i have to multiply A and B or is this mean $"A \cup B"$ (?)

Comment: @AsafRosemarin thankyou but what is $\varDelta $ mean? $E=\{A,B\in V_{n,m}| |A\varDelta B| = m \}$

Comment: @AsafRosemarin  i searched it , it is symmetric difference..but here if A and B same sets how can there exist symmetric difference(?)

Comment: If $A=B$ then $A \varDelta B = \phi$, so if $E$  is what I wrote, then you won't have edges between $A$ and itself (which makes sense). However, I don't know for sure if it's what you meant, maybe you can link the source of the problem?